# Generate all combinations from multiple lists with repeat lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have multiple lists, some of them are repeats and I need all combinations, excluding ones where the same element from a repeated list is chosen. For example, I have

```
import itertools
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
list3 = [4,5,6]
list4 = [7,8,9]
a = [list1,list2,list3,list4]
print list(itertools.product(*a))
```

which outputs

```
(1,4,4,7)
(1,4,4,8)
(1,4,4,9)
(1,4,5,7)
.
.
.
```

etc, as you'd expect, but what I want it to do is output every combination, without repeating elements from lists 2 and 3. Like this:

```
(1,4,5,7)
(1,4,5,8)
(1,4,5,9)
(1,4,6,7)
(1,4,6,8)
(1,4,6,9)
(1,5,6,7)
(1,5,6,8)
(1,5,6,9)
(2,4,5,7)
.
.
.
```

I'd obviously like to avoid having to remove them manually after creating the list, but any help on how to do this efficiently is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is a generator expression with a filter:

```
print list(item for item in itertools.product(*a) if item[1] != item[2])
```

If two items are considered the same if they contain the same elements, and if each item is guaranteed to contain no repeated elements, you can discard duplicates by changing them into `set`s and only adding them to your `list` if they're not already in it:

```
result = []
for item in itertools.product(*a):
    if item[1]==item[2]:
        continue
    item = set(item)
    if item not in result:
        result.append(item)

print result
```

Comment: That helps with the repeats, thank you, but I also don't need the order to matter for the elements from repeated lists, for instance, I get 
(1,4,6,8) and (1,6,4,8) when I only need one of those.